# Python Decimal() calculation with prec=8 produces a Decimal with a prec > 8. How to ensure always get prec=8?

Tags: python, math, decimal, precision

After setting my precision to 8 and doing calculations with Decimal(), I am getting an answer with a precision of 10. How to always ensure my answer has a precision of 8?

```
getcontext().prec = 8
(Decimal('2')/100) * Decimal('0.00050000')
>>>Decimal('0.0000100000')
```

```
getcontext().prec = 8
print((Decimal('2')/100) * Decimal('0.00050000'))
>>>Decimal('0.0000100000')
```

```
getcontext().prec = 8
(Decimal('2.00000000')/100) * Decimal('0.00050000')
>>>Decimal('0.0000100000')
```

I need an answer from the calculation that always has a prec=8, but with these small numbers I'm getting this Decimal object with a larger precision. The way I've got my fields stored in the database (`sql-alchemy`) is as `field = db.Column(db.Float(asdecimal=True, decimal_return_scale=8))`

Is there a way to dynamically get my variable/answer to have .prec=8. Like ideally i'd say:

```
getcontext().prec = 8
variable = (Decimal('2.00000000')/100) * Decimal('0.00050000')
variable.prec(8)
>>>Decimal('0.00001000')
```

Comment: You seem to be thinking of fixed-point precision rather than floating-point precision. `decimal.Decimal` is floating point. `prec=8` means 8 significant digits, not 8 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: You can use the `round` function from python like `round(variable, 8)`. But it would ignore the trailing zeros

Comment: I (think) I need 8 decimal places after the zero, as per an API rules on precision. On a Binance API, the data type its requesting is Decimal, with a precision of 8.